# Is it possible to get the public ip address from the sender of an http(s) request to the firebase rest api?

Tags: firebase, http, https, google-cloud-firestore, godot

I'm currently working on a Godot multiplayer project where players will make HTTP(s) requests to a REST API I have set up with Firebase's cloud firestore database. I'm wondering if it is possible to get the IP address of whoever sent the request, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database REST API is not going to reflect back to you any IP addresses.  You will need to instead provide your own backend API for the clients to call if you want to collect their IPs.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer! If I may ask a follow-up question: If I were to implement my own backend API, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: That sort of question is too broad for stack overflow.  You have essentially unlimited options to choose from.  I suggest doing your own research to learn about your options.